# JavaFx nodes set.....() -> NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

First thanks for pointing out the mistakes i made creating this post.

I narrowed my code down as much as i could, hope it is clearer now.

So the problem occuring is a `NullPointer Exception` for example when i try to change the visibility of a label after switching from on scene (root) to another. Here it is `headlineLeaderboard.setVisible(false)`. Printing `headlineLeaderboard` out before the method is called somehow returns null.

This somehow doesn`t happen with every scene in my application even tho the switching progress is identic.

Now to the code:

In the main class the stage, main scene etc. is created. There is also the method to switch the root of the scene.

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private Scene scene;

// 
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("ReaktionsTest");
    try {
        FXMLLoader loaderMain = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane paneMain = (AnchorPane) loaderMain.load();
        MainWindowController mainWindowController = loaderMain.getController();
        mainWindowController.setMain(this);
        scene = new Scene(paneMain);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void setSceneLeaderboard() {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("LeaderboardWindow.fxml"));
        scene.setRoot(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In the application `MainWindowController` is the controller for all scenes. `handleLeaderboardAufrufen()` first changes the scene. In the next step the NullPointer occures.

```
public class MainWindowController {

private Main main;

@FXML private Label label1; 
@FXML private Button leaderboard;  
@FXML private TextField fieldName; 
@FXML private Label headlineLeaderboard;

public void setMain(Main main)   {
    this.main = main;   
}

@FXML
public void handleLeaderboardAufrufen() {
    main.setSceneLeaderboard();
    headlineLeaderboard.setVisible(false);
}
}
```

The fxml of LeaderboardWindow looks like this: (In `MainWindow.fxml` the same controller is used: `fx:controller="application.MainWindowController"`)

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="500.0" maxWidth="750.0" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="750.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainWindowController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="leaderboardTable" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="92.0" prefHeight="331.0" prefWidth="729.0">
      </TableView>
      <Label fx:id="headlineLeaderboard" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="23.0" text="Leaderboard" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="36.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error code:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.MainWindowController.handleLeaderboardAufrufen(MainWindowController.java:25)
... 58 more
```

Comment: You should post your `StackTrace`.  We also don't have any idea where some of the "relevant code you posted is located." You should have posted a minimal about of code that reproduces the problem and allow us to copy and paste it to run the code.

Comment: I agree with Sedrick; this is too much code for us to read through every line and try to find the error. If you need help creating a [mcve], click that link and follow along :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes. Hope its better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment from @Sedrick, you should update your post as he suggests and as is written in the guidelines.

However, I will point out the one thing I'm thinking could be the cause of this and anyone may feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

You look to be, from controller A connected to your FXML A, trying to access the Text variable from FXML B (ResultView).

```
main.setSceneResult(); 
System.out.println("resultText  " +resultText );
resultText.setText("hello");
```

As you've shown in the code above, you add the root to the scene (main.setSceneResult), though the current controller (which I am assuming you are in) don't know of the new parent and it's members. What you could do is to create a new controller for the ResultView, I would suggest like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(resultView.fxml));
ResultViewController resultViewController = new ResultViewController();
loader.setController(resultViewController);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Then you may, from controllerA, call a method on controllerB to update the Text variable.

You could try something like the code below just to verify that it works.

```
ResultViewController resultViewController = main.setSceneResult(); /*This method returns the controller which has access to the ResultText variable (if correctly setup which it looked like you had done)*/
resultViewController.setResultText("hello");
```

I hope this may help you, if not then I suggest that you update your post with a runnable example :)

Edit: 
I looked through the code some more as I didn't have that much time earlier when I wrote my reply. It's difficult to figure out what is happening, if you have several controllers or if you only have the 1 controller (MainWindowController). My example above might help so please do try it, but really I am not sure after having looked at the code again. 
Also, I'm not sure if there is a reason behind you specifying the controller in the fxml instead of creating it and setting it to the loader as I did in my suggestion. I am also not sure if you are using your "MainWindowController" as the controller for both the ResultView and the current View. If that is the case then I would really suggest that you create one controller that handles the ResultView, and then have the main controller handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it out tomorrow or monday and let you if it worked.

Comment: MainWindowController in my case is the controller for alle scenes. I updated the post so it is more clear. I already tried creating a new MainWindowController with every scene switch (not a new controller for new scenes just creaing a new MainWindowController) like you suggested , but  it didn`t havae any impact in the NullPointer Exception

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot for yout help!

Comment: Thats great! I was just about to look at your updated post to see if I could figure it out. I'm glad I was able to help :)